# How to add custom object within the closure block

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

Currently I am trying to create an Array to hold UITextFields that can be added to AlertController as completionHandler. So lets say I have

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Another Test" message:@"Another Message" UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UITextField *test = [UITextField alloc] init];
test.text = "Hello";

[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField * _Nonnull textField) {

    }];
```

I am just curious, if there is any possibility to pass "test" object within completion Handler? I did tried created a typedef and that definition can be passed towards configuration Handler, but for some reason in swift it behaves little odd, doesn't takes the reference of the block thats being passed from Obj-C to Swift.

Any help in this regards will be very useful. I was trying to utilize typealias from Swift, and be utilize in Obj-C, but that doesn't works. Is there a way to define a closure and use it in Obj-C?

Comment: @Paulw11, I think the completion handler returns Void as per the signature. I tried returning the object assigned outside of it, and it still didn't worked.

Comment: You're right. My bad. You have to configure the text field it gives you.

Comment: I do not understand your Q: `test` is automatically known in the handler. This is the whole point with closures.